# How to download VHD Disk of a VM from azure using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have tried searching for a way to download VHD disk of a VM from Azure, but couldn't find any.
The only way I found to download is by downloading it manually using the steps provided in the link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/download-vhd

If anyone has a way to download it using python, please share...

Thanx in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the link you referenced tells you what you need to do to download a .VHD

However, if you want to use Python, there is a [library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) you can use to make common tasks easier.

See [this file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/block_blob_usage.py) especially for some more information on how to read blobs in an Azure Storage Account.